# How to install numpy for Python 3.6.5 explicitly

Tags: python, numpy

This is not a duplicate question, I want to install numpy for python 3.6.5. it works on 3.4 on the same machine but I need it for 3.6, I tried "pip3 install numpy" and "apt-get install python3-numpy", they both install it but it's for 3.4 not 3.6.

To get things more clear, I use 3.4 on daily basis and 3.6.5 comes with Blender 3D, so I can't uninstall any of them. I'll do anything if I have to build numpy for 3.6.5. please help.... I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I can't upgraded at this state.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
pip3.6 install numpy
```

Greetings

Comment: thank you for your concern but I have fixed the issue by overwriting the numpy installation file with new ones I manually downloaded

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3.6 install numpy --user
```

worked like a charm...

```
python3.6  
Python 3.6.3 (default, Nov 28 2017, 15:38:13)    
[GCC 5.4.1 20160904] on linux  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>> import cv2  
>>> import numpy  
>>> cv2.__version__  
'4.1.2-openvino'  
>>> numpy.__version__  
'1.17.4'  
>>>
```